# Unity - determine items collision with different "tags"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Three different colored blocks colliding with three other different colored blocks]

I'm beginning with Unity2D. I have three different colored blocks (the three lower block in the picture) going up at a constant force. Each of the lower blocks are labeled by tags of "Red", "Blue", and "Yellow". The upper blocks are also tagged by their respective colors.

Also, each object has a `isTrigger` `boxcollider2D` attached. I want to `Debug.Log` a message like "Game Over", if two different colors collide with each other.

I understand that I need to use `OnTriggerEnter2D` in some capacity, but I don't know how. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[EDIT] Currently this is what I have (and it isn't working the way I want it to).

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.tag != "Red")
    {
        Debug.Log("Game Over");
    }
    if (col.tag != "Blue")
    {
        Debug.Log("Game Over");
    }
    if (col.tag != "Yellow")
    {
        Debug.Log("Game Over");                 
    }
}
```

Comment: So what are stuck on? Give some code?

Comment: I've added some code.

Comment: Please do some research before posting your question,  if you spent 5 minutes googling how to use OnTriggerEnter2D,  and how to compare tags you would have this answer.

Comment: A hint... the object with this script also contains a gameObject(`this.gameObject`) which happens to contain its tag.

Comment: `col.gameObject.tag`

Comment: @Bijan `col.gameObject.tag` is the same tag as `col.tag`

Comment: so `if(col.tag == this.tag)`

Comment: @Bijan yep, but in the case of this question it would be `!=`

Comment: Thanks for all the help! In my hierarchy I have 3 different boxes for each color. For example for the Red box would I have to separate script to with the code if (if(col.tag != this.tag); . Basically, do I have to have a seperate script for every box?

Comment: @Nick_Var thats one way to do it yes.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting. ! Marks on your if statements. This means if the tag does not equal. It would help if you would say what you mean by not working the way you want. If does not equal is what you want then I don't see a problem and it must he somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

OnTriggerEnter2D is called every time, your gameObject collides with another collider. One of the colliding gameobjects needs a rigidbody2D or else OnTriggerEnter2D will not be called.

I assume you got a problem with the logic of the if statement and not the call of OnTriggerEnter2D and you want to call a "Game Over Function" if the tags of the colliding gameobjects are not the same.

So you want to compare the tags of both colliding gameobjects, not the tag of one colliding object with a few other tags.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag(gameObject.tag) == false)
        Debug.Log("This is NOT the same Color!");
    else
        Debug.Log("This is the same Color!");
}
```